# Failure to connect to sql server 2008 instance

Tags: java, database, sql-server-2008, hibernate, jdbc

I've setup the instance SQLEXPRESS via SQL Server 2008 R2 installation, added a security login with all server roles, one called 'sqluser'.

Facing an exception whenever i try pool a connection.. Connection string is being built from following:

```
<db.driverClassName>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</db.driverClassName>
<database.username>sqluser</database.username>
<database.password>qwerty</database.password>
<database.schemaname>dbo</database.schemaname>
<database.url>jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\SQLEXPRESS</database.url>
```

But connections face this stacktrace root cause:

```
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection to the host localhost, named instance sqlexpress failed. Error: "java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out". Verify the server and instance names and check that no firewall is blocking UDP traffic to port 1434.  For SQL Server 2005 or later, verify that the SQL Server Browser Service is running on the host.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:190)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.getInstancePort(SQLServerConnection.java:3589)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.primaryPermissionCheck(SQLServerConnection.java:1225)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:972)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:827)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1012)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1556)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1545)
    ... 71 more
```

The server authentication is SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode. However, when i specify the -S property, login fails.

There is no firewall enabled and SQL server even accepts connections from remote hosts.

```
C:\Users\user>sqlcmd -U sqluser -P qwerty -Q "Select * FROM testdb.dbo.testtable"
```

Output:

```
integer
-------
      1
      2
      3
      4

(4 rows affected)
```

However when specifying 'localhost' the query fails... Question is Why?

```
C:\Users\user>sqlcmd -S localhost/sqlexpress -U cpt -P 1234 -Q "Select * FROM cpt.dbo.testme"
```

Output:

```
HResult 0x43, Level 16, State 1
Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [67].
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0 : A network-related or in    stance-specific error .....
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0 : Login timeout expired.
```

Changing 'localhost' with '%COMPUTERNAME' is same result if someone would be wondering. The server is running as a LocalSystem instance.

*edit*
Assigning answer to the lama allthough it was primarily hints :) Here is my solution to the problem:

1) check that tcp ip all listener port is set to 1434
2) check that the connection string is properly setup (database.url)
3) check that login has sufficient access (not related to this specific stacktrace)

Comment: check this link for jdbc url format http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428(v=sql.90).aspx

Comment: connection string is known to work, and suggestion about ';instanceName=SQLEXPRESS' changes nothing. we connect using hibernate

Comment: looking back at this; wonder where the backslash slipped into the dos..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are we fairly sure the only issue is just 'localhost' here?

Just to rule that in or out can you try sqlcmd with the slash the right way and the correct login (as described earlier in your post) see if it works or not:

```
sqlcmd -S localhost\sqlexpress -U sqluser -P qwerty -Q "Select * FROM cpt.dbo.testme"
```

You mention that it accepts commands from remote hosts, but your example command line did not specify the server to connect to, so this couldn't possibly be running from a remote host.

Is the jdbc code running on the same machine as the SQL Server? This will tell us if we can exclude firewalls from the analysis.

Comment: makes sence - and the sqlcmd.exe connects and processes sql with backslash! Only thing left is that the how hibernate jdbc fails. How can a known good connection string change from one installation of the toolchain to another?

Comment: sql server and bean factory are both localhost. the connection is made through a servlet container which fails in its construct chain, due to the trying to get configuration variables from the sqlexpress instance

Comment: I gather from your response that the SQLCMD above worked? So you get a timeout error when you use servlet / JDBC?

Is there another tool that you can use to test JDBC (and take the servlet out of the picture?) Can you use this utils.dbping thing? (Sorry I don't know much about Java) http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/jdbc/troubleshooting.html

Comment: Are you saying its the config code? can you dump the config that the connection code is using and verify that it is using the correct (expected) JDBC connect string?

Comment: Also be aware that the name 'schema' can be ambiguous accross database platforms. In SQL it is more important to designate the database as opposed to the schema. However JDBC might call a SQL database a schema - not sure. Regardless this would not contribute to a timeout error - so don't worry about it for now.

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed this issue, do not remember if it was the **/** between HOST / INSTANCE or tcp/ip not listening. These are my scripted commands for creating login, db and for setting up SQL services correctly:

Batch job which will set mixed auth and open tcpport 1433:

```
echo off
rem is sql server installed at this build number?
reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS" >nul
if %errorlevel% EQU 0 (
echo SET : SQLEXPRESS\MSSQLServer\SuperSocketNetLib\Tcp\Enabled : True
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\"&_
 "MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQLServer\SuperSocketNetLib\Tcp" /v Enabled /t REG_DWORD /d 0x1 /f
echo SET : SQLEXPRESS\MSSQLServer\SuperSocketNetLib\Tcp\ListenOnAllIPs : True
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\"&_
  "MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQLServer\SuperSocketNetLib\Tcp" /v ListenOnAllIPs /t REG_DWORD /d 0x1 /f
echo SET : SQLEXPRESS\MSSQLServer\SuperSocketNetLib\Tcp\IPAll\TcpPort : 1433
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\"&_
  "MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQLServer\SuperSocketNetLib\Tcp\IPAll" /v TcpPort /d 1433 /f
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer" /t REG_DWORD /v LoginMode /d 2 /f
)
```

SQL Script that will create the login and set mixed authentication on

```
CREATE DATABASE dbnamehere;
GO
USE [master]
GO
CREATE LOGIN [usernamehere] WITH PASSWORD=N'1234', DEFAULT_DATABASE=[dbnamehere], CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF
GO
EXEC master..sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame = N'usernamehere', @rolename = N'bulkadmin'
GO
EXEC master..sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame = N'usernamehere', @rolename = N'dbcreator'
GO
EXEC master..sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame = N'usernamehere', @rolename = N'diskadmin'
GO
EXEC master..sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame = N'usernamehere', @rolename = N'processadmin'
GO
EXEC master..sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame = N'usernamehere', @rolename = N'securityadmin'
GO
EXEC master..sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame = N'usernamehere', @rolename = N'serveradmin'
GO
EXEC master..sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame = N'usernamehere', @rolename = N'setupadmin'
GO
EXEC master..sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame = N'usernamehere', @rolename = N'sysadmin'
GO
EXEC xp_instance_regwrite N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', N'Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer', N'LoginMode', REG_DWORD, 2
GO
```

And lastly, assert that the correct services are running on machine reboot

```
@echo off
sc config "MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS"  start= auto
sc failure "MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS"  actions= restart/180000/restart/180000/""/180000 reset= 86400
sc config "SQLBrowser"  start= auto
sc failure "SQLBrowser"  actions= restart/180000/restart/180000/""/180000 reset= 86400
net stop MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS
net start MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS
sc config "SQLBrowser"  depend= "MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS"
net stop SQLBrowser
net start SQLBrowser
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
C:\Users\user>sqlcmd -S 192.168.01\sqlexpress
    -U cpt -P 1234 -Q "Select * FROM cpt.dbo.testme"
```

Check: SQL-Server-Log if the SuperSocket is running on localhost. If not, start configuration.

Comment: This is not even a valid IP address, and even if it was, you cannot assume that it is the SQL Server's IP address.